# Is boolean not supported with flatMap?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, flatmap

I'm facing this error with `flatMap` but not with `map`. Is boolean operation is not supported with `flatMap` transformation?

```
scala> val array = Array("age","astro")
array: Array[String] = Array(age, astro)

scala> val baseRdd = sc.parallelize(array)
baseRdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:29

scala> val flat2 = baseRdd2.flatMap(x => x.contains("a"))
<console>:31: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Boolean
 required: TraversableOnce[?]
         val flat2 = baseRdd2.flatMap(x => x.contains("a"))
```

Comment: What is your expected result? An RDD with two booleans, both true?

Comment: @stholzm yes . But i can do tat with map. but my doubt is why flatmap is not returning the boolean result as a TraversableOnce

Comment: Well, both `map` and `flatMap` return RDDs, the difference is that you have to pass a function that returns `TraversableOnce` to `flatMap`. It will then "flatten" the data structure, hence the name. `flatMap` is just defined that way. You *could* pass `x => Array(x.contains("a"))` to `flatMap`, but it would be more simple to just use `map` in that case.

Comment: @stholzm it makes sense. pls  update ur answer so tat i can accept your answer . :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`flatMap` expects a function as parameter that returns `TraversableOnce`, i.e. a list or something. `x.contains("a")` returns a plain boolean - maybe you meant to use `map` instead of `flatMap`?

Both `map` and `flatMap` return RDDs, the difference is that you have to pass a function that returns `TraversableOnce` to `flatMap`. It will then "flatten" the data structure, hence the name. `flatMap` is just defined that way. You *could* pass `x => Array(x.contains("a"))` to `flatMap`, but it would be more simple to just use `map` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

map evaluates a function over each element in the list, returning a list with the same number of elements. whereas flatMap invokes the function f for the element(s) of the collection producing a new collection. flatMap is simply a combination of map with flatten.

```
flatMap[B](f: A => Container[B]): Container[B]
```